# How to add color to bash output of `git diff --name-status` by file status?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, bash

I would like to style the bash output for `git diff --name-status` so that the files with status `D`, `M`, and `A` are different colors.

To style general git bash I use the `color` options in `.gitconfig`.

```
# .gitconfig
[color]
  branch = auto
  diff = auto
  status = auto
[color "branch"]
  current = yellow reverse
  local = yellow
  remote = green
[color "diff"]
  meta = yellow bold
  frag = magenta bold
  old = red bold
  new = green bold
[color "status"]
  added = yellow
  changed = green
  untracked = cyan
```

To style an output for a command like `git log` I can use `--pretty=format` in an alias like below:

```
# .gitconfig
[alias]
  log = log --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

However, I have been unsuccessful using `--pretty=format` for `git diff --name-status`.

The output I would like to style is currently not styled and looks like:

```
$ git diff <branch> --name-status
M       .gitignore
M       README.md
A       diagnostic.js
D       diagnostic.md
```

Is there a way to style the output `git diff --name-status` by status type?

Comment: I have never crossed the `git diff --name-status` flag, but it looks a lot like `git status --short` which has built-in colors. Would that do the trick for you?

Comment: @JoanRieu that would if you could tell `git status` to show a specific commit. `git status --short` is great though; this is exactly what I'd want to see from a colorized `--name-status` option

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can colorize the output of `--name-status` without entirely reproducing its output with `--pretty=format:...`

But if you want file names with colors summarizing changes, the `--stats` flag can be passed to many commands, including `git diff <branch --stat` and `git log --stat`.

It shows file names, with a colorized `+++--` suffix, e.g.

```
$ git diff master --stat                                               
 lib/thing.go      |  5 +++--
 lib/thing_test.go | 23 +++++++++++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 28 insertions(+), 2 deletion(-)
```

and the `+`s and `-`s will colorize according to your git config

Comment: I don't think it's possible to reproduce the list of files using `--pretty`... see: [`git show --pretty`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats) ([`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) doesn't seem to support `--pretty`)

Answer (score -1):

If you really really need colour in your life this might work:

```
# pick your colours
Red='\033[0;31m'; Colour_Off='\033[0m'; Cyan='\033[0;36m'; 

# find another branch (you could enter <branch>)
BRANCH=$(git br|grep -v '*');

# take the output of git diff and pain the first column red and the reset cyan.
git diff $BRANCH --name-status|awk "{print \"$Red\" \$1 \"\t\" \"$Cyan\" \$2 \"$Colour_Off\"}"
```

You could create an alias for this in bash or a paint.sh